# Images inside Vue components not working with Vite + Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

All of the images worked fine before using laravel with Vite. Now images from inside Vue components stopped working and can't find any solution for this.

I have these images in laravel inside:

```
/resources/images/drivers/2023/
```

Standings.vue (*resources/js/components/sections/Standings.vue*)

```
const driverImages = import.meta.glob("/resources/images/drivers/2023/*")
```

For example images that are served over are not found:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/images/countries/2023/backgrounds/catalunya.jpg
```

But images served over laravel are found and working that are used directly in blade template:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5173/resources/images/flag.svg
```

All of the images appear in `public/build folder` after running `npm run build` but are not visible on frontend

Comment: Any one fixed it ?

Comment: None. I refactored methods for retrieving images from folders and stoped using import.meta.glob()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored current method so instead of getting all images from imported folder, I now use method to match images inside folder like this:

```
 getDriverImage(name) {
            return new URL(`/src/assets/images/drivers/2023/${name}.webp`, import.meta.url).href
        },
```

This is the only way where images are transformed correctly after `npm run build`. This is now different approach, where you have to know exact image name to match the asset, vs previous `import.meta.glob()` where all assets inside folder were returned.